# How can I find if a subnode exists

Tags: delphi-7, nativexml

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UsersF Ver="1.1">
    <row User="1" Pin="2y44ic" ExtPag="full"/>
    <row User="2" pin="tfde88" ExtPag="e45" />
    <row User="3" Pin="9gr444466gg" Level="nov" GamePag="3" />
</UsersF>
```

And this is the code that I get access and put a string-grid...
I use the nextgrid ...

```
procedure showXmlToString;
Count:= 0;
Conf.nxtgrd.AddRow(71);
Conf.nxtgrd.BeginUpdate;
with FXml.Root do
for i := 0 to NodeCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Nodes[i].Name <> 'Ver' then
      begin
        Conf.nxtgrd.Cell[0,count].AsString := Nodes[i].Nodes[1].Value;
        Conf.nxtgrd.Cell[1,count].AsString := Nodes[i].Nodes[2].Value;
        Conf.nxtgrd.Cell[2,count].AsString := Nodes[i].Nodes[3].Value;            
        Conf.nxtgrd.Cell[3,count].AsString := Nodes[i].Nodes[4].Value;
       count := count + 1;
      end;
  end;
```

When it come to line that the node not exits I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

To accessing the attributes you can use `TXmlNode.AttributeCount` to iterate numbers of attributes available. If the main point of this code is to obtain the attributes, you can access them using `TXmlNode.Containers`.

Let say you want to get all the attributes name & value, you can using following iteration:

```
with FXML.Root do
for i := 0 to ContainerCount - 1 do
begin
  Log(Format('ContainersName=%s AtribNumber=%d',[Containers[i].Name,i]));
  for j:=0 to Containers[i].AttributeCount-1 do begin
    Log(Format('AttribName=%s AttribVal=%s',[Containers[i].Attributes[j].Name,Containers[i].Attributes[j].Value]));
  end;
end;
```

In this example `Log` procedure will display the string to the screen. As the result the output will be like this:

```
ContainersName=row AtribNumber=0
AttribName=User AttribVal=1
AttribName=Pin AttribVal=2y44ic
AttribName=ExtPag AttribVal=full
ContainersName=row AtribNumber=1
AttribName=User AttribVal=2
AttribName=pin AttribVal=tfde88
AttribName=ExtPag AttribVal=e45
ContainersName=row AtribNumber=2
AttribName=User AttribVal=3
AttribName=Pin AttribVal=9gr444466gg
AttribName=Level AttribVal=nov
AttribName=GamePag AttribVal=3
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: oooh.. do you mean checking the Attributes (User,Pin,Level..), you can use `TXmlNode.AttributeCount` to iterate and retrieves the attributes value using `TXmlNode.AttributeValue`.

Comment: yes i mean the attributes... the txmlnode.attributecount is wrong bcs some times gives me the same number but dont tell me which node is missing...

Comment: This is work sybond but really is a bit confusion if you want to find a simple subnote is exist... i think the native xml have something like that... if getvaluebynodename('pin') <> '' then exist... Thanks by the way...